# USE Raw SQL in Django

Tags: php, python, django, django-views, django-database

I recently migrated from PHP to django. I am creating a project which works on django.. I am used to write custom sql in php and hence i want to use raw() to filter results from my database in django.

However i am not able to fully understand how django works..

Please find my code below.

Currently i am receiving the below mentioned output

```
[('11677795635',), ('12345',)]
```

I want to use some **for** loop and print results in the below mentioned format.

11677795635

12345

can you please help me on how to for loop in django ..

In PHP,
the same was possible by

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT  abcdashboard_customerinfo.customerbuyingid FROM abcdashboard_customerinfo WHERE abcdashboard_customerinfo.customerbuyingid in (select DISTINCT abcdashboard_orders.customerid from abcdashboard_orders)");
$queryrun=mysql_num_rows($query);    
for ($f=0; $f <$queryrun; $f++)
    { 
       ${'customer'.$f}=mysql_result($query,$f, 'customerbuyingid');
       echo ${'customer'.$f};
     }
```

---

models.py

```
class customerinfo(models.Model):
    customerbuyingid = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='invalid customer id in database')
    customername = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='invalid customer name in database')
    customerphonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='0000000000')
    customermailid= models.CharField(max_length=80, default='email@email.com')

class orders(models.Model):
    orderid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    orderstatus = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    externalpurchaseid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    externalstatus = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customerid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ops = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    orderdate = models.DateField()
    updatedon = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

---

views.py

```
def index(request):
    all_customer = customerinfo.objects.all()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT abcdashboard_customerinfo.customerbuyingid FROM abcdashboard_customerinfo WHERE abcdashboard_customerinfo.customerbuyingid in (select DISTINCT abcdashboard_orders.customerid from abcdashboard_orders) ''')
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    print (row)  
    context = {"row": row}
    return render(request, "abcdashboard/index.html", context)
```

---

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
<h2 align="center"> SQL Queries display </align> </h2>

{% block content %}

{{ row }}

{% endblock %}
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't do this. If you want to write Django, you should write Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

in views.py:

```
row = cursor.fetchall()
print (row)  
context = {"row": row}
```

with:

```
ids = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    id = row[0]
    ids.append(id)
context = {'rows': ids}
...
```

in index.html:

```
{{ row }}
```

with

```
{% for id in rows %}
{{ id }}
{% endfor %}
```